# Virtual fields in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am still thinking about the best way to work with tags in Symfony. I did look at FPNTagBundle, but I didn't find an easy way to work this into the CRUD forms.

I also found http://xoxco.com/clickable/jquery-tags-input which would give a perfect widget. As it in- and outputs comma separated strings, I thought I could just define a virtual field in my model, that displays the tag object array as such a list.

```
public function addTag(\Wein\StoreBundle\Entity\Tag $tag)
{
    $this->tag[] = $tag;
    $this->makeTagFieldFromTags();
}

public function setTagField($tagField)
{
    $this->tagField = $tagField;
    $this->makeTagsFromTagField();
}
public function makeTagsFromTagField()
{
    $tags=explode(',', $this->tagField);
    $tagObjects=array();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        $tag=trim($tag);
        $tagObject = **???**;
        $tagObjects[]=$tagObject;
    }
    $this->tag=$tagObjects;
}

public function makeTagFieldFromTags()
{
    $tags=array();
    foreach($this->tag as $tag) {
        $tags[]=$tag->__toString();
    }

    $this->tagField = implode(',', $tags);
}
```

The I could just use a form element on this field. Unfortunatly, I don't see a way to translate the strings into Tag-objects insite the entity, as I don't have access to the entity manager.

So what is the clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean way is to use a [data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html). It transforms the strings into your tag entities at the "form" side and not in the entity, so you can keep your entity clean.